# Spectral analysis of timestamps

Tags: spectral-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a dataset that contains only the timestamps of occurring events, i.e. I have for ~10^5 events the millisecond-precise time when the respective event happened (i.e. the data is unary, containing only '1's). I would like to perform spectral analysis (i.e. Fourier or Lomb-Scargle) on this data to find periodicities.

Naively, I would create equidistant time bins to assemble something like daily count rates of the event, and perform Fourier analysis on that. Plotting these daily count rates over time shows that there is some very clear seasonality in the data, but I'm especially interested in periodicities that are not immediately apparent. Fourier analysis of these daily count rates appears to support that. However, because the timestamps are much more precisely given than by just their dates, using daily (or even hourly) bins does not seem like the best method.

In case it is important: the dataset is by no means perfect and contains a whole bunch of instrumentation effects, i.e. there are time intervals where no events could be detected, etc ...

I hope this question is adequately stated. If not, please feel free to ask for more information!